# What is the input for JsonSerializer.Deserialize method which causes a null return value?

Tags: c#, .net, jsonserializer

I have a simple JSON object which look like the following in sunny day scenario:

```
{
  "JsonProp1": "4ADx4ADx",
  "JsonProp2": "4AH/4ADx",
  "JsonProp3": "4AKq4ADx"
}
```

I have also implemented a class for that.

```
internal class JsonData
{
    public JsonData(byte[] jsonProp1 , byte[] jsonProp2 , byte[] jsonProp3) 
        {
            JsonProp1 = jsonProp1;
            JsonProp2 = jsonProp2;
            JsonProp3 = jsonProp3; 
        }
        public byte[] JsonProp1 { get; set; }

        public byte[] JsonProp2 { get; set; }

        public byte[] JsonProp3 { get; set; }
}
```

My question would be the following:
what would be the input parameter for the deserializer to retrive null?

```
JsonData? jsonData= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonData>(InputJson);
```

In case the input is wrong (e.q. not json format) it throws an exception. If the input is correct syntactically but not compatible it return with JsonData but properties are null.

Comment: If `InputJson` was the string `"null"`.

Comment: If you make your setters `private` then the result shall be `null`. There are many instances why you can get a null. The question is (if I mat ask) why do you want to know?

Comment: @FortyTwo The property setters are irrelevant. The JSON value `null` is the only thing that will cause `jsonData` to be null.

Comment: @FortyTwo it is not true, I have tried it. But now I see that the question is duplicated. Sorry for that.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Than you for the answer!